# Show call failing with a grouped and aggregated dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use sum after groupBy, like this,

```
val b = a.groupBy($"key").agg(sum($"value"))
```

Here the schema of a is of the following type,

```
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
```

While the schema of b is of the following type,

```
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sum(value): long (nullable = true)
```

But when I do `b.show`, I get this error.

```
cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy 
to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ 
of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

What could be the reason for this error? I am using Spark 2.3.2 and running the code with an Apache Zeppelin note.

Comment: The issue is most likely related to how `a` is created, not the operations shown in the question. Including that and the full stack trace would help

Comment: Well if I use show with a, it works fine, but b.show gives this error.

Comment: That's a [dependency problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9219) (and related topics on SO), not the code issue.

Comment: Show takes a subset of rows and might skip plenty of them while `groupBy` before `show` forces processing them all which might explain.

Comment: @MetallicPriest can you do a count on `a` instead of show?

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally Yes count works fine, for both a and b.